# Fast Connection to a SQL Server with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am grabbing json data from a messaging bus and dumping that json into a database. I've had this working pretty well with psycopg2 doing ~3000 entries/sec into postgres. For a number of reason we've since moved to SQL Server 2016, and my entries dropped to around 100 per second.

I've got a functioned called insert_into() that inserts the json to the database. All I've really done to my insert_into() function is change the library to pyodbc and the connection string. It seems that my slow down is coming from setting up then tearing down my connection each time my function is called ('conn' in the code below). If I move the line that setup the connection outside of my insert_into function, my speed comes back. I was just wondering two things:

1. Whats the proper way to setup connections like this from a SQL Server perspective?
2. Is this even the best way to do this in postrgres?

For SQL Server, the server is 2016, using ODBC driver 17, SQL authentication.

Slow for SQL Server:

```
def insert_into():
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=server1;DATABASE=json;UID=user;PWD=pass')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        for i in buffer_list:
            command = 'INSERT INTO jsonTable (data) VALUES (%s)' % ("'" + i + "'")
            cur.execute(command)
        cur.close()
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, pyodbc.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
```

Fast for SQL Server:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=server1;DATABASE=json;UID=user;PWD=pass')

def insert_into():
    #conn = None
    try:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        for i in buffer_list:
            command = 'INSERT INTO jsonTable (data) VALUES (%s)' % ("'" + i + "'")
            cur.execute(command)
        cur.close()
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, pyodbc.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)

This daemon runs 24/7 and any advice on setting up a fast connection to MSSQL will be greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: Your solution seem legit to me. For Postgres you might want to look at connection pooling. https://pynative.com/psycopg2-python-postgresql-connection-pooling/. I've never used this with SQL Server though. You could look into using SSIS, but I went from using SSIS for a lot of tasks with SQL Server to Python just because SSIS seems really touchy and prone to failure.